# "As a child" or "being a child"?

Tags: word-usage

My essay was revised by a native speaker.  He made a revision as follows.  Could anyone tell me the reason behind the revision?  Thanks a lot.

Origial: Although as a little child at that time, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.

Revised: Although being a little child at that time, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.

Comment: 'as' is too familiar

Comment: It depends on the bit you’ve replaced with “...”.

Comment: I would advise leaving out both words. "Although a little child at that time..." , which implies "(I was) a little child". It's correct to say "As a child, I did this", but "as" doesn't fit with "although".

Comment: @KateBunting Depending on context, "Although a little child at that time..." could be ambiguous (i.e not making it clear it's me).

Comment: To me, "although" implies that somewhere in that sentence there will be a contradictory statement that will offset the fact you were a little child, such as "Although just a little child at the time, I was responsible for feeding my 7 younger siblings every morning before school."  "Being" does not have the same expectation.

Comment: You can see, Lee, from the comments you are getting that without the rest of the sentence, it is not possibly to be sure what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you everyone for these valuable comments.  I have updated the question by providing the complete sentence

Comment: @MrLister There is no ambiguity in the sentence being discussed because the next phrase starts with 'I'

Comment: Find someone else  to revise your work. The suggested revision is horrible. Use *Although **I was**  a little child at that time, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world*.

Answer (score 0):

"although" doesn't play well with "as" **nor** "being" in both of your examples. "although" signals a dependent clause, which, in your case, is exactly what "as" does as well. So they conflict.

Better edits of your sentence could be:

1. Although I was a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.
2. Though I was a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.
3. Even though I was a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.
4. Even as a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.
5. Despite being a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world.

Now, you might get away with the sentence below:

"Though a little child, I knew the location and names of all the countries all over the world."

But I think it's awkward.